# MYSQL, Take value from 'reported users' table and use name to delete from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm not sure the best way to describe this,

I have a table that contains reported usernames from my users

```
'Name' 'reason' 'gender' 'date'
 joe     FAKE     male   10/10/2013
```

the gender column tells me which table the username resides, in this case 'male_users'

is there some way/function to take the name column and the gender and go to the corresponding table and delete that username, without me having to manually copy the name - > change table -> search for usernames like 'joe' -> delete -> start over

I hope this makes sense!

Thanks

Comment: You could try a case construct.

Comment: You have sexually segregated tables? Is that really necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do it will be to use two commands in row:

```
DELETE FROM male_users WHERE name IN(
SELECT name FROM users WHERE <logic> AND gender='male'
);
DELETE FROM female_users WHERE name IN(
SELECT name FROM users WHERE <logic> AND gender='female'
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the multiple-table `DELETE` syntax together with some outer joins as follows:

```
DELETE   m, f
FROM     reported_users r
 LEFT JOIN   male_users m ON m.username = r.Name AND r.gender =   'male'
 LEFT JOIN female_users f ON f.username = r.Name AND r.gender = 'female'
```

But really, why have the separate `male_users` and `female_users` tables?  Why not have a single table with a column containing the user's sex?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself in the end, the answers above are also correct, however i chose to create a php script to read the values and display a button beside each entry to allow me to delete from the table with a simple

```
'DELETE FROM $gender_of_table WHERE username = $username'
```